# How to set italic typeface for future text in current cursor position on edittext and to bring it back to normal?

Tags: java, android, spannable, sketchware

I want to apply Text Format Options on `EditText`. I am able to apply Bold, Italic, Strike, Underline after spacebar is trigger but i can't bring it back to normal typeface. I want to apply this typeface on the current cursor position, also able to bring it back to normal typeface.

i am using Sketchware App.

here's my code:

```
if (editText_is_Italic) {
editText_is_Italic = false; btn_italic.setColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
StyleSpan Spantxt = new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL);
int start = edittext2.getSelectionStart();
int end = edittext2.getSelectionEnd();
int flag = Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE;
edittext2.getText().setSpan(Spantxt, start, end, flag);
}
else {
if (!editText_is_Italic) {

    editText_is_Italic = true;
    btn_italic.setColorFilter(0xFFFFC107, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    StyleSpan Spantxt = new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC);
    int start = edittext2.getSelectionStart();
    int end = edittext2.getSelectionEnd();
    int flag = Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE;
    edittext2.getText().setSpan(Spantxt, start, end, flag);
}
}
```

I've try to use `.removeSpan();` and `.clearSpans();` on removing span, also i've try `Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE` to set this on current cursor position. But no one succed.